# How to access PickerFlyout's app bar in a WP 8.1 XAML App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm writing a custom picker with the [PickerFlyout class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pickerflyout.aspx). By setting the ConfirmationButtonsVisible property to true, the flyout will show an application bar with an accept and a cancel button.

My problem is that the picker I am writing does not always have a valid value, and therefore I would like to disable the accept button when it does not make sense. **Is there a way to do this in a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app ("Store app")?**

Other possible solutions:

An alternative solution would be to show my own app bar instead of the one given by ConfirmationButtonsVisible, which is possible by setting one in the Opening event. However, when this is done if the "overflow dots" of the application bar is clicked, the flyout will close. Apparently there is no way to prevent a flyout from closing.

If all else fails I will have to write a custom [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I would rather not do this because the opening and closing animations used by PickerFlyout do not seem to be available as resources (internal to the class maybe?).

Comment: Can you explain why you can't have a default option that is automatically selected? This would be the expected usage for the picker.

Comment: The picker consists of a search box and a list view. For some searches no results may be returned.

Comment: I did some further testing and noticed that the problem of the flyout closing only happens when the app bar has items in SecondaryCommands. As long as there are items only in the PrimaryCommands section the flyout seems to stay on screen.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are items only in the PrimaryCommands section the flyout stays on screen when the overflow dots are tapped. Thus it is possible to temporarily replace the page's app bar with a new one for the duration of the flyout as long as no items in SecondaryCommands are needed. The accept button can be disabled in this new app bar.